# Calculate Quarters R Code

Tags: r

I have a data set which I need to calculate how many quarters in the past from the present day, each date is.  A quarter equals 92 days.

I think I have most of the code written correctly, its the calculating quarters portion that is wrong.

Can I strip the days from the QTR?  Or is there a better way to calculate the quarters.  Also I need to do this without using a custom package.  So no lubridate, Datetime, etc.

I want to get a data frame like this (these results are made up):

> Date       Diff      QTR
>
> 1 2014-06-24  342 days  4
>
> 2 1999-04-11 1201 days 137
>
> 3 1979-01-01 13000 days 1254

Instead I get this:

> Date       Diff      QTR
>
> 1 2014-06-24  342 days  4 days
>
> 2 1999-04-11 1201 days 137 days
>
> 3 1979-01-01 13000 days 1254 days

```
Date=c("2014-06-24","1999-04-11","1979-01-01")
Quarter=as.Date(Date, origin="1970-01-01")

Fun=function(Quarter){
Today=Sys.Date()
Diff=difftime(Today,Quarter[],units='days')
QTR=floor(Diff/92)
data.frame(Date,Diff,QTR)
}

Fun(Quarter)
```

Comment: You can strip the diff's attributes with `as.vector()`

Answer (score 0):

Add in `as.numeric`

```
Date=c("2014-06-24","1999-04-11","1979-01-01")
Quarter=as.Date(Date, origin="1970-01-01")

Fun=function(Quarter){
  Today=Sys.Date()
  Diff=difftime(Today,Quarter[],units='days')
  QTR=as.numeric(floor(Diff/92))
  data.frame(Date,Diff,QTR)
}

Fun(Quarter)
R> Fun(Quarter)
        Date       Diff QTR
1 2014-06-24   216 days   2
2 1999-04-11  5769 days  62
3 1979-01-01 13174 days 143
R>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Stedy!  I swear I tried as.numeric with no luck before deciding to post.  That was the obvious solution!